# What is the std::vector::iterator's index in the vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, swap

I have an `std::vector<Bullet> bullets` and in the for-loop below I want to remove a bullet from the vector if it's not alive anymore.

My plan is to remove the element with `pop_back()`. If there are more than one element in the vector I want to first swap the element that is to be removed with the last element in the vector, and then call `pop_back()`.

```
for (std::vector<Bullet>::iterator b = bullets.begin(); b != bullets.end(); ++b) {
  if(!b->isAlive()) {
    if (bullets.size() > 1) {
      std::iter_swap(bullets + ..., bullets.end());
    }
    bullets.pop_back();
  }
}
```

The problem is the first parameter in `iter_swap`. I looked up http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/iter_swap/ and the syntax for the first parameter is the vector + the position of the element.

How do I find out `b`'s index in the vector?

Comment: Either I'm missing something, or you need an *iterator* for the first element and already have the right iterator: `b`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::remove()` or `std::erase()` instead of having to `swap()` and `pop_back()`?

Comment: @Cyber Because that takes linear time while swap-and-pop takes constant time.

Comment: For the record, `b - bullets.begin()` would give the index.

Comment: @delnan Your `for` loop takes linear time. Remove-erase _is_ swap-and-pop.

Comment: @Oktalist Assuming a single application of `remove_if` instead of the `for` loop, yes, I read it as keeping the for loop and removing each dead bullets with another remove-erase. Also, while the overall complexity is O(n) in any case, swap-and-pop performs fewer moves (at the cost of messing up the order).

Comment: Don't you want `iter_swap(b, bullets.end() - 1)` (emphasis on "- 1")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the condition governing whether an element is to be removed or not is :

```
object->isAlive()
```

Then you should use an STL way to do the removal, namely the erase-remove idiom :

```
bullets.erase(std::remove_if(bullets.begin(), bullets.end(), 
[](Bullet const& b) {
   return !b.isAlive(); 
}), bullets.end());
```

---

Now, to answer your particular question an iterator's `it` index in a vector `v` can be obtained like so :

```
auto indx = std::distance(v.begin(), it);
```

Answer (score 3):

There's an easier way to filter a `std::vector`.

```
#include <algorithm>

auto part = std::remove_if(
    bullets_.begin(),
    bullets_.end(),
    [](const Bullet &bullet) { return !bullet.isAlive(); });
bullets_.erase(part, bullets_.end());
```

This will partition the vector into the alive and dead bullets, and then you delete the segment with the dead bullets.

The `std::remove_if()` function is like `partition()` but only the order of the first partition is preserved.

Comment: Thanks. What type is that `auto` there? My doesn't support it.

Comment: @A.D. Time to upgrade your compiler... or at least turn on modern C++ support.  That's C++11.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was wondering what the type is so I can exchange the `auto` for it and then use your solution.

Comment: @A.D. If you don't support `auto` you'll probably need to replace the lambda with a functor object as well.  You can replace `auto` with the iterator type for your vector.